# Salesforce for Outlook synchronization issue

Tags: community, salesforce-for-outlook, sync

I connected my iphone to the computer to charge and received the following error:
Salesforce for Outlook can't sync. You have one or more sync folders missing. Please have a look at the attached screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the log file I there is the following stacktrace:

```
2016-03-10 10:57:17,126 INFO  [Contact] *********** Starting Sync ***********
```

2016-03-10 10:57:17,126 INFO  [Sync] Direction:Sync Conflict Setting:ClientWins
2016-03-10 10:57:17,126 INFO  [Contact]SyncEngine status changed to GettingSalesforceChanges
2016-03-10 10:57:17,136 INFO  [Contact]SyncEngine Status: received 0 creates, 0 updates, 0 deletes, and 0 errors from Sfdc Sync Connector
2016-03-10 10:57:17,136 INFO  [Contact]SyncEngine status changed to GettingOutlookChanges
2016-03-10 10:57:17,216 INFO  [Contact]SyncEngine Status: received 8 creates, 0 updates, 0 deletes, and 0 errors from Outlook Sync Connector
2016-03-10 10:57:17,226 INFO  [Contact]SyncEngine status changed to Matching
2016-03-10 10:57:17,226 INFO  [Contact]SyncEngine status changed to DoingConflictDetection
2016-03-10 10:57:17,226 INFO  [Contact]SyncEngine status changed to ApplyingSalesforceChanges
2016-03-10 10:57:17,226 INFO  [Contact] Applying Outlook changes to Salesforce: 8 creates, 0 updates, 0 deletes
2016-03-10 10:57:17,586 ERROR [Contact] Create  to SFDC gave error(s) Sfdc.Server.SfdcServerCreateUpdateException: Required fields are missing: [LastName]
 for Outlook record
2016-03-10 10:57:17,586 ERROR [Contact] Create  to SFDC gave error(s) Sfdc.Server.SfdcServerCreateUpdateException: Required fields are missing: [LastName]
 for Outlook record
2016-03-10 10:57:17,586 ERROR [Contact] Create  to SFDC gave error(s) Sfdc.Server.SfdcServerCreateUpdateException: Required fields are missing: [LastName]
 for Outlook record
2016-03-10 10:57:17,596 ERROR [Contact] Create  to SFDC gave error(s) Sfdc.Server.SfdcServerCreateUpdateException: Required fields are missing: [LastName]
 for Outlook record Walgreens
2016-03-10 10:57:17,596 ERROR [Contact] Create  to SFDC gave error(s) Sfdc.Server.SfdcServerCreateUpdateException: Required fields are missing: [LastName]
 for Outlook record Paladar Colombiano 
2016-03-10 10:57:17,596 ERROR [Contact] Create  to SFDC gave error(s) Sfdc.Server.SfdcServerCreateUpdateException: Required fields are missing: [LastName]
 for Outlook record NationStar William Mccumber 
2016-03-10 10:57:17,606 ERROR [Contact] Create  to SFDC gave error(s) Sfdc.Server.SfdcServerCreateUpdateException: Required fields are missing: [LastName]
 for Outlook record Carlos Krystal
2016-03-10 10:57:17,606 ERROR [Contact] Create  to SFDC gave error(s) Sfdc.Server.SfdcServerCreateUpdateException: Required fields are missing: [LastName]
 for Outlook record Dr Sarro Dermatologist

Could you please explain what is causing the error and advise an appropriate solution?

Regards,

Dilyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help docs [here](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000199078):

> First, double click on the SFO system tray icon (as explained above)
>   to open the actual error message with the details. If the error
>   message says "Required fields are missing: [LastName]" then follow the
>   steps below to resolve the issue.
>
> 1- You can click on the contact name on the SFO error screen (it is in
>   a form of hyperlink that you can click on to open the contact in
>   Outlook) to open the contact's detail page   2- Click on Full name
>   3- The “Check Full Name" windows will open   4- Update the Last name
>   as it is a mandatory field in Salesforce. If your contact does not
>   have a Last Name or you are syncing a company as a contact, or for any
>   reasons you do not have a Last name you can use a dot "." or comma ","
>   or such to populate the Last Name field   5- Click OK and then click
>   on Save & Close
>
> You may have to repeat steps 1-5 if you have more than contact with
>   missing Last Name
>
> The screen shot below is from Outlook 2007 but the steps are the same
>   for other versions of Outlook     [image: User-added image]
>
> 6- Click on Retry on the SFO error screen or if you have already
>   closed it, right click on SFO system tray icon and click on Sync |
>   Sync Now
>
> 7- Sync should complete successfully and you should not see that error
>   message again